# SAS - Space as the separator of decimals

Tags: sas

I have numbers with values from 10 to 100 million in SAS datastep

It is necessary that there be a space instead of a comma or dot as a separator

For example:

```
10234332 -> 10 234 332
```

Which format I can use?

I tried to user COMMAXw.d and other formats, but it doesn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [picture format](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0n990vq8gxca6n1vnsracr6jp2c.htm).

```
proc format;
    picture commas
        low-high = '00 000 000 000 000'
    ;
run;

data test;
    format value commas.;
    value = 100000000;
run;
```

```
value
100 000 000
```